# Is it really possible to use Pyroscope on AWS managed grafana?

Tags: grafana, pyroscope

Grafana workspace is configured with enabled plugins management.  Pyroscope plugin is there in the list of available ones.  However, the "install" button just does not show up.  What do?

Comment: If I read this right, it would come in the v10 release https://github.com/aws/amazon-managed-grafana-roadmap/issues/64

Comment: thanks @possum.  it's good to know that it's not me having misconfigured something.  the plugin page in our instance says that Pyroscope support is built-in (very misleading), I guess it's just a copy-paste from original grafana's text and has nothing to do with reality of AMG.